# What does the phrase 「やった人」 really mean?

Tags: words, meaning

I am a bit confused on what the 「やった人」really mean.

You can see it used as a Twitter hashtag, but truthfully the meanings elude me.

Does it mean a people who can do something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the short form of やったことがある人

"People who have done this" in English.

Most commonly used on sites like Twitter, as in "retweet this if you have done it"

Comment: Ah! So it's a short form....
Uuughh..... So that's why the content of the twitter is so random....

Comment: No, that is not a short form of anything.